# Can I use DJI Mobile SDK with any cross platform framework?

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, flutter, dji-sdk

Has anyone tried to use DJI mobile SKD together with any cross-platform development framework? Ionic, React-Native or Flutter?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they don't have a Cordova plugin available, it won't work out of the box. At least not in Ionic.

In order for it to work, you need to expose the API of the plugin to its JavaScript counterpart so that Cordova knows how to call certain functions.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently working on a react native wrapper for the DJI MSDK. Feel free to check out our [repo](https://github.com/Aerobotics/react-native-dji-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

## A Flutter plugin in 2022

This is a library that you can use to develop cross-platform DJI iOS & Android apps.

The library is still under development, read more from the following:

- https://github.com/DragonX-cloud/dji_flutter_plugin
- https://pub.dev/packages/dji/install

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use React Native. You will need to build your own custom native modules for every feature/class in the DJI SDK separately for iOS and Android that you want to implement. So you need a good understanding of how those work.

For example an objective C stub is below. You can build native modules in ObjC/Swift, Java/Kotlin and more info on how that works can be found in the RN [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro).

```objectivec
@implementation RCTDJIWaypointMission

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(DJIWaypointMission)

RCT_REMAP_METHOD(loadMission, loadMission:(NSDictionary*)mission resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejector:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
// method body
}
```

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'
const { DJIWaypointMission } = NativeModules

DJIWaypointMission.loadMission(mission)
```